# directory services group query changing randomly

Tags: c#, .net, active-directory, directoryservices

I am receiving an unusual behaviour in my asp.net application.  I have code that uses Directory Services to find the AD groups for a given, authenticated user.  The code goes something like ...

```
string username = "user";
string domain = "LDAP://DC=domain,DC=com";
DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(domain);
search.Filter = "(SAMAccountName=" + username + ")";
```

And then I query and get the list of groups for the given user.  The problem is that the code was receiving the list of groups as a list of strings.  With our latest release of the software, we are starting to receive the list of groups as a byte[].

The system will return string, suddenly return byte[] and then with a reboot it returns string again.

Anyone have any ideas?

(marc_s) Added code sample:

```
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ldapSearchBase); 
DirectorySearcher userSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry) 
  { SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree, 
    CacheResults = false, 
    Filter = ("(" + txtLdapSearchNameFilter.Text + "=" + userName + ")")
  }; 

userResult = userSearcher.FindOne(); 
ResultPropertyValueCollection valCol = userResult.Properties["memberOf"]; 

foreach (object val in valCol) 
{ 
    if (val is string) 
    {
        distName = val.ToString();
    } 
    else 
    { 
        distName = enc.GetString((Byte[])val); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide some more source code, especially the part where you read from your SearchResultCollection.

Comment: // i can't edit the question, brief code:
DirectoryEntry dirEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + ldapSearchBase);

DirectorySearcher userSearcher = new DirectorySearcher(dirEntry)
 {
   SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree,
   CacheResults = false,
   Filter = ("(" + txtLdapSearchNameFilter.Text + "=" + userName + ")")
  };
userResult = userSearcher.FindOne();
ResultPropertyValueCollection valCol = userResult.Properties["memberOf"];
foreach (object val in valCol)
{
  if (val is string) {
   distName = val.ToString();
  }
  else {
    distName = enc.GetString((Byte[])val);
  }

Comment: is this still a problem?  If so, "the latest release" of what software?  How many groups (including nested groups) is the user a member of?

Comment: This is with an AD server running windows 2000.  I can get some more version numbers if you direct me to the relevant dll or applications.

Comment: Okay.  I don't have any 2000 machines I can try anything on.  Frankly, I won't have any 2003 DCs, soon.

You didn't answer the question about how many groups the user is a member of.

Comment: oops, i missed that one.

they are a member of 12 groups with no nested groups.

Comment: When you are getting a byte[], what does enc.GetString((Byte[])val) return?  Does it return the group name?